# Spark - Java - Filter Streaming Queries

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I've a Spark application that receives data in a dataframe:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.readStream().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "topic").load().selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) as key");
String my_key = df.select("key").first().toString();
if (my_key == "a")
{
do_stuff
}
```

Basically I will need to in case of value a then I apply some transformations on the dataframe otherwise I apply other transformations.

However, I am dealing with streaming queries and when I tried to apply my code above I got:

```
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()
```

The error happens when I make the first operation.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sole my problem using:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.readStream().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "topic").load().selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) as key").filter(functions.col("key").contains("a"));
```